# How do i check GO version in Gitlab Omnibus

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ee

Is there a way to check GO version in Gitlab. When i try to run `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` I get this  which says `Go Version : Unknown`

I want to know the version of Go so that I can check if I can integrate some monitoring tools like Dynatrace for my Gitlab instance because Dynatrace only supports fewer versions.

```
Current User:   myuser
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.6.6p146
Gem Version:    2.7.10
Bundler Version:1.17.3
Rake Version:   12.3.3
Redis Version:  5.0.9
Git Version:    2.28.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version:     unknown

GitLab information
Version:        13.3.6-ee
Revision:       d7bc82f4b06
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     11.7
URL:            https://mygitlab.system
HTTP Clone URL: https://mygitlab.system/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  myuser@mygitlab.systems:some-group/some-project.git
Elasticsearch:  no
Geo:            no
Using LDAP:     yes
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers:
```

Answer (score 0):

GitLab Omnibus packages do not contain any go system since go sources are already compiled. Go is only needed for installation from source (See e.g. [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20908) gitlab issue).

GitLab's CI pipeline uses Go 1.14 since April 2020. See the corresponding yml file [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L20). If you should use an older GitLab release you can check the history of the file.

According to [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Go.gitlab-ci.yml) build file GitLab's Go binaries seem to be statically linked. So you will have to enable support for statically linked Go applications in Dynatrace as described [here](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/go#known-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Go` not part of `GitLab` itself, but rather the version of `Go` we used to compile the various components of `GitLab`, you'd need to check the build environment for the `Omnibus` packages.

Based on that, the only possible way is check it here for the latest release:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-omnibus-builder/-/blob/master/docker/VERSIONS